# MPTCP in user mode

Tags: networking, tcp, kernel-mode, user-mode-linux

Is there any implementation of MPTCP in user mode, not kernel mode? If no, is there any suggestions to reuse kernel mode source code in user mode?

http://www.multipath-tcp.org

https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp

Answer (score 2):

There is a python/scapy based implementation: https://github.com/nimai/mptcp-scapy

Furthermore, you can check out an MPTCP proxy userspace implementation in c to get you started, if you want to develop yourself: http://open-innovation.alcatel-lucent.com/projects/mptcp-proxy 
Look under DocManager: Project Documentation -> Uncategorized Submissions

Answer (score 0):

I've created a protocol serving the same purpose as MPTCP with a full, cross-platform, user-space implementation. The key difference is that it sits on top of TCP, i.e. multiple standard TCP connections are aggregated into one logical connection.

The source code is available at https://github.com/surban/aggligator.